# Line getting replaced instead of getting inserted

Tags: python, list, file, append

I am reading content from a file. I need to insert a line(if not already present) after checking a certain line with a specific keyword(function) and store the function name. I tried inserting it after the keyword is matched but the next line is getting replaced instead of insert.

Original File

```
   function a:
     line not present

    function b:
       line is present :b
```

Expected File

```
  function a:
  line is present :a
  line not present.

  function b:
  line is present :b
```

Result File

```
  function a:
  line is present :a


   function b:
   line is present :b
```

I tried the following code:

```
  words=[]
  with open('sample.sv',"r") as f :
    for line in f:
      words.append(line)
      found=re.search('function',line)
      if found is not None:
         word=line.split(' ')[1]
         next_line=next(f)
         if 'line is present .*' not in next_line:
           words.append("line is present({p}) :".format(p=word)
```

Can someone suggest what should I add or delete to get things working.

Comment: We need the actual code you're using, instead of guessing how to fix your syntax errors.

Comment: Try again with looping condition - `for line in f.readlines()`

Comment: (1) `in` or `not in` doesn't process regexes. (2) `next_line` isn't added to words.

Comment: @aquaman I tried your suggestion.It didn't work

Comment: @Prune That's the actual code.

Comment: @Saurabh: the posted code dies on a syntax error at `with open('sample.sv',"r:) as f :`, due to the quote imbalance.

Comment: @MichaelButscher what do you suggest for that. In those 2 lines,I wanted to check whether it's present in the next line and if not add the line,

Comment: @Prune .Sorry about that. Fixed it

Comment: One more thing, your file is in **r** mode, try changing it to **a** mode.

Comment: @Saurabh (1) You already used the `re` module, do it again. (2) Append the `next_line` to `words` if you want it in the output (I guess that `words` is finally used to compose the output which isn't part of the shown code).

Comment: @aquaman First the file should be read, then it should be overwritten. I don't see where append mode is useful here. Either open it twice (once r-mode, once w-mode) or use `r+`-mode (reading and writing).

Comment: @aquaman I am editing the original file and writing it to another output file. For that also, do I need to change the mode?

Comment: @MichaelButscher .Appending next_line to words worked. Thanks a lot guys for your help. Cheer!

Comment: @MichaelButscher Got confused, my bad.

Comment: Another problem appreared as I appened next_line in words. In the other function, "line  is present :b" got duplicated.